# spring-xd kafka sink(file) write ascii code

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-xd

I'm testing apache-kafka with spring-xd.

I'm following this example. http://spring.io/blog/2015/04/15/using-apache-kafka-for-integration-and-data-processing-pipelines-with-spring

It works fine and I'm tring spring-xd.

```
xd> stream create kafka-source-test --definition "kafka --zkconnect=localhost:2181 --topic=event-stream | log" --deploy
```

I send json string to kafka.

> {"name":"tester1","age":"0"}

It works but log is

```
INFO dispatcher-1 sink.kafka-source-test - [B@2907e63b
```

so I try to sink.file

```
xd> stream create kafka-source-test --definition "kafka --zkconnect=localhost:2181 --topic=event-stream | file" --deploy
```

and check out put file 
I met this ascii code

> 123,34,110,97,109,101,34,58,34,116,101,115,116,101,114,50,34,44,34,97,103,101,34,58,49,125

It's mean this json string.

> {"name":"tester1","age":"0"}

How can I get the msg with json String? 
Help me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use --outputType=text/plain or --outputType=application/json. either of this should work. it should be passed as a parameter to kafka source in stream definition.

Comment: Yes, thanks. More specifically: `stream create kafka-source-test --definition "kafka --zkconnect=localhost:2181 --topic=event-stream --outputType=text/plain | file" --deploy`

Answer (score 1):

try using option --encoding in the kafka source definition.

Comment: update source/kafka.properties
set stringDecoder class to StringDecoder from DefaultDecoder.